# Streaming Kmeans Spark JAVA

Tags: java, scala, spark-streaming, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

Hi Basically we wanted to use KAFKA+SPARK Streaming to catch Twitter Spam on our thesis. And I wanted to use streamingKmeans. But I have very newbie and serious question:

In this spark StreamingKmeans scala example (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/StreamingKMeansExample.scala) there is one line of code for prediction:

`model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lp => (lp.label, lp.features))).print()`

Why I need to pass the "LABEL" with features ? I mean, am I getting wrong the whole idea ? Isn't we want to predict the "label" ? How am I going to predict my tweets if they are spam or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the prediction only `lp.features` is used, whereas `lp.label` is considered as a key that is carried over. Quoting from the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans):

> Use the model to make predictions on the values of a DStream and carry over its keys.

I guess in your example you would simply want to replace `predictOnValues` by `predictOn`

Comment: Thank you sir. I will definitely try this one. BTW do you know any gitter or slack rooms I can join to ask my questions ?

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. I wouldn't any such rooms, but I think that SO is always very open towards answering well-posed questions